# Как настроить отображение Status Bar в iOS-приложении?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток.

У меня такая проблема: я написал приложение для iPad, мне нужно, чтобы оно открывалось на весь экран и не было статус-бара. В настройках проэкта я поставил галочку возле Hide status bar while application launch, но статус бар не пропал. Как его убрать? Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь в plist "View controller-based status bar appearance" и задай ему "NO".

[image]